# Is RequireJS execution order guaranteed for dependent scripts once their dependency is loaded?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In RequireJS, if multiple scripts have dependencies on a module, are those scripts guaranteed to get executed in the order they are defined once the module is loaded?

Basically, with the following setup, is there ever a time that `2` would get logged before `1`?

```html
<head>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
    <script async data-requiremodule="jquery" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
// script1.js
require([
    'jquery'
], function () {
    console.log(1);
});
```

```
// script2.js
require([
    'jquery'
], function () {
    console.log(2);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain that they are, but you shouldn't rely on this behaviour from inside the scripts.

Comment: The reason that I ask is because in my case, `script2.js` does an AJAX request, and I fire an event out of it on its success callback. I'd like to make sure that `script1.js` loads before it because it hooks into that event. Is there a better way to do this if I'm not to rely on this behavior?

Comment: I meant that you make the module declared by *script1.js* a dependency (requirement) of the *script2.js* module (or at least of the code that fires the event). But I guess there's a trade-off between decoupling the modules through use of events and ensuring that they work together.